# How to solve issue in jest unit test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, typescript, jestjs

I have a unit test for a ReactJs/Typescript project that has a reference to a module called nock.js, and using jest:

```
import nock from 'nock'
...

afterEach(() => {
   nock.cleanAll();
})
```

When I run the test I get an error in the .cleanAll statement:

```
TypeError: nock_1.default is not a function
```

However when I change the import statement to :

```
var nock = require('nock');
```

The issue is solved. How can I still use import instead of require ? Is this an issue with the jest configuration? This is the config:

```
"jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js"
    ],
    "testRegex": "/__tests__/.*\\.(ts|tsx|js)$"
  },
```

Comment: Maybe this issue? https://github.com/node-nock/nock/issues/584 (Jest tries to mock 'nock'…)

Comment: @helb did not work for me this one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a module has a default export, you can use:

```
import nock from 'nock'
```

But if it doesn't have a default export, you'll need to use:

```
import * as nock from 'nock'
```

Answer (score 4):

I met the same exact issue, and fixed it by adding the following config to my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
...
"esModuleInterop": true
...
}
```